# Laravel excel library prints blank excel file

Tags: php, laravel

What's wrong with my code, I tried to export my data table using framework Laravel. The file is downloaded with empty content.
**StockModel.php**

```
namespace App; 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 
class Stock extends Model {
        protected $table = 'stock_tb'; 
        protected $primaryKey = 'id'; 
        protected $fillable = ['stock_id', 'input_date', 'quantity']; 
}
```

**AdminController.php**

```
use Excel;
use App\Stock;
use App\Exports\StockExport;
class adminController extends Controller {
    public function __construct() {  }
    public function printStockReport(){       
       return Excel::download(new StockExport('07/01/2020'), 'ado.xlsx');
    }
```

**StockExport.php**

```
namespace App\Exports;
use App\Stock;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
class StockExport implements FromQuery
{
    protected $id; 
    public function __construct($date_var)
    {
        $this->date = $date_var;
    }  
    public function query()
    {
      return Stock::query()->where('input_date', $this->date)->get();
    }   
}
```

**Router**

```
Route::get('admin/printStockReport', 'adminController@printStockReport');
```

Fyi: I run the SQL code on my RDBMS with criteria input date **07/01/2020**. It returns 129 records.

Thank you

Comment: Be sure to not ->get() the results! https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/from-query.html

Comment: I have tried some possibles regarding to the query. Removing the get(), changing the criteria, the fields, but still not working.

Comment: Try adding   `use Exportable;` trait and  `protected $date;` property to your class

Comment: Argh...I just solved it. I missed to use use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable; on my stockExport.php. Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `->get()` , according to `laravel-excel` documentation no need to that.

Comment: Thanks man..solved it